Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'FirebaseRemoteConfig' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0:
When I was running flutter project on iOS simulator this error occurred:
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 16 Pro in debug mode...
Xcode build done.                                           38.0s
Failed to build iOS app
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Compiling for iOS 12.0, but module 'FirebaseRemoteConfig' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 13.0: ../build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseRemoteConfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig.framework/Modules/FirebaseRemoteConfig.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftmodule
Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 16 Pro.
Exited (1).
My pod file iOS:platform :ios, '13.0'
Simulator iOS: 18,1

You have to change minimum deployments version by go to folder ios in your project reveal in finder double click on Runner.xcworkspace
Select Runner in Target like picture below now change it to IOS 13.0

if it still not work you can try to run this command
pod install --repo-update

